# $.ajax is not working in IE: SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, http-post

I am trying to use a `jQuery` dialog box to do a popup modal in my `ASPX` page. The problem now is `$.ajax` causes a syntax error in IE. Here is my code;

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'testModalPopup.aspx',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    data: { "param1" : "abcd1" },
    beforeSend: function () {
        //some loading indicator
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#theDialogBox").html(data);
        $("#theDialogBox").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 'auto'
        });
        $("#theDialogBox").dialog("open");
        $("#theDialogBox").closest(".ui-dialog").removeClass("ui-widget");
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //handle error
    }
});
```

The error I'm facing is:

> **SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>
>   File: jquery.min.js, Line: 12, Column: 25164**

Comment: What jquery version you are using?

Comment: is it working into Chrome ,FF?

Comment: How to check jquery version?

Btw, it works in Chrome, but i need the system to support in IE.

Comment: I think i found the problem. It caused in $("#theDialogBox").html(data);. But not sure how to make the changes to this.